# How to detect amazon sitemap

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, sitemap

I am trying to scrape some products from amazon.com, but it I can't find it in its robots.txt

I tried

```
amazon.com/sitemap.xml
amazon.com/sitemap.xml.gz
amazon.com/sitemap1.xml.gz
amazon.com/sitemap1.xml
```

all turn-up nothing

I also tried sitemap detector such like

```
https://seositecheckup.com/tools/sitemap-test
```

The result shows Amazon doesn't have a sitemap.
Is that true? or I didn't have the correct approach.

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-see-a-sitemap-for-any-website

Comment: @Gallaecio I read every answer of that question and didn't help to figure out how to find amazon's sitemap.

Comment: Then they most likely don’t have one.

Comment: so how search engines like google and bing to crawl the website?

Comment: They either use generic crawling (i.e. go to the home page and follow all links recursively) or they have their own, proprietary crawling implementation for the site.

Comment: Accidentally find [Why does Amazon not have a sitemap?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Amazon-not-have-a-sitemap) and this question at same page in google.

Answer (score 1):

A sitemap is not strictly required for a website to be indexed. Google, Bing and other search engines have advanced algorithms and crawlers that are designed to discover and index content on the web, with or without a sitemap.

Amazon might not have a sitemap one or it's generated dynamically for various purposes, and it might be restricted to certain bots/ip addresses.

Here is a sitemap for amazon payment services https://paymentservices.amazon.com/sitemap/

Here is a similar question on stackexchange https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49186/why-important-big-sites-dont-include-a-sitemap

Comment: I'd state it stronger than "sitemaps are not required to be indexed". Pages rarely get indexed just because they are listed in a sitemap, and sitemaps never help rankings. At best sitemaps help SEO by providing slightly more granular visibility in search engines' tools.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Answer (score -1):

Look at [robots.txt](https://www.amazon.fr/robots.txt), you will see a sitemap link at bottom with access denied.
This ressources may be accessible only to robots (specific user-agent, IP...).

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible that amazon doesn't have a Sitemap. Amazon as product is built on a very way when it comes to SEO. The pages that you see on the website are canonicalised pages. The pages you see from the website are duplicate and missing few modules like Breadcrumb, etc as compared to canonical URLs.
Amazon Nav menu is not every exhausted which let crawlers to crawl P3 level pages.

So the way website is built there has to be sitemap.

Now, as they need to keep website data private and at the same time promote the same data on search engines, they must have showing serving it from some AWS server or they are using dynamic serving or Maybe they have submitted the URLs all together from a different Domain, sub-domain, private domain, etc
The whole agenda of sitemap is to serve URLs to crawler. No sure just speculating because it is hard to figure out the sitemap URL of Amazon.